# mongodb getSiblingDB method does not exist in python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, anaconda, jupyter

This is My code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = pymongo.MongoClient("...")
 watchCursor = db.getSiblingDB('test_uk').Malaria.watch()
```

test_uk is my database and Malaria is my collection.Im using jupyter notebook in anaconda

Error was:

```
   3318         raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you    
meant to "
   3319                         "call the '%s' method on a 'Collection' 
object it is "
```

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'getSiblingDB' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such
method exists.

Im using Python 3.7.
Please help me!

Comment: I think you need to specify the Client you are using when choosing a db. Why not use ‘pymongo.database.Database(client, DBname)’ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
watchCursor = client['test_uk'].Malaria.watch()
```